# DPRP is disabled for this merchant. Paypal Error

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I am trying to Create a billing agreement with payment method:credit card.

Here is my code:

```
public void CreateBillingAgreement()
{

   var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();     
   var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();    
   var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
```

//Note: Billing agreements for credit card payments execute automatically when created. There is no need for the user to approve the agreement or to execute the agreement.

```
        var credit_card = new CreditCard()
                   {
                       billing_address = new Address()
                       {
                           city = "Johnstown",
                           country_code = "US",
                           line1 = "52 N Main ST",
                           postal_code = "43210",
                           state = "OH"
                       },
                       cvv2 = "874",
                       first_name = "Test",
                       last_name = "abc",
                       expire_month = **,
                       expire_year = ****,
                       number = "********",

                       type = "visa"
                   };

        List<FundingInstrument> funding_instruments = new List<FundingInstrument>();
        var fund = new FundingInstrument
        {
            credit_card = credit_card
        };
        funding_instruments.Add(fund);
       var  payer = new Payer
            {
                payment_method = "credit_card",
                funding_instruments = funding_instruments
            };

       var shipping_address = new ShippingAddress
       {
           line1 = "1234",
           city = "California",
           state = "California",
           postal_code = "95070",
           country_code = "US"
       };
       string Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:ssZ");

        //Make API call
       var agreement = new Agreement
       {
           name = "T-Shirt of the Month Club Agreement",
           description = "Agreement for T-Shirt of the Month Club Plan",
           start_date = Date,
           plan = new Plan
           {
               id = "P-*****************" 
           },
           payer = payer,
           shipping_address = shipping_address
       };
       var CreateExecuteAgreement = agreement.Create(apiContext);
```

But getting this error,

> //{"name":"DPRP_DISABLED","message":"DPRP is disabled for this
>   merchant.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DPRP_DISABLED","debug_id":"********"}
>           }

Answer (score 1):

DPRP = DirectPayment Recurring Payments.  This is very specific.

To use this you would need to be using "PayPal Website Payments Pro 3.0", where you would typically use the DoDirectPayment API to process credit cards, and that is $30/mo.

On top of that, you need to add Recurring Payments, and then you would use the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API with credit card details included directly (which must be what this SDK you're using is doing).  This is considered DPRP, and this is an additional $30/mo on top of the fee for Pro.

Many people get confused because if you sign up for "Payments Pro Recurring Billing" they will probably put you into the PayFlow version, in which case you would need to use the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment / CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

So the first thing you need to do is very which version of Payments Pro you are using, and then verify whether or not you have Recurring Payments / Billing enabled on top of that.

Comment: How can I verify this on my paypal account ??  version of Payments Pro

Comment: Did they give you a login for http://manager.paypal.com separate from your regular www.paypal.com login?

Comment: Hi @Andrew Angell I got the login for manager.paypal.com, can you please guide me how to enable recurring payments.

Comment: What? Does that mean if I want to be able to get monthly payments via credit cards I'd have to pay $60/month to paypal?

Comment: Yes, but if you [contact me directly](https://www.angelleye.com/contact-us) I can get you in touch with a PayPal account manager who can get at least half of that waived for you, if not the whole thing.